# Selenium + TestNG + SQL @BeforeMethod: Database setup

Tags: java, postgresql, selenium, testng

We are designing a test suite for a web app, using Selenium as the automation framework and TestNG as the test framework. Our app consistently makes use of comparisons between the UI and the back-end PostgreSQL database, and as such for all of our test cases, the appropriate preconditions must be setup so that our test cases will run instead of fail due to missing data or existing data that shouldn't exist. We are currently considering the best way to setup the preconditions for each test case, given that the test cases are dependent on the state of the database.

According to this reference here by Microsoft, at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb381703(v=vs.80).aspx, the best approach to setup the tests (although this is for database unit testing as opposed to our type of test) is to "...[u]se a data-generation tool to set the database state, before you run your collection of [sic] tests." Failing that, we can always "restore a database from backup", although it could run into issues with any schema changes, or setup the test preconditions case-by-case.

Right now we are implementing the database setup on a case-by-case basis using SQL statements to either delete or insert the appropriate data. However, we have run into issues with this approach because the SQL updates that we run are often missing in-between steps in modifying the SQL database. We have thus considered as well switching over to using various API requests to setup the preconditions, as such requests often encompass multiple SQL update statements in an enclosed transaction. However, this also creates an issue in that it relies on the API requests to be fully confirmed and tested as working properly (something else we are working on).

So, my question is: what would be the best approach in setting up the database so that the appropriate preconditions are fulfilled? It appears that the best practice would simply be to reload the database from a backup, but there may be a different approach that would be better suited to our situation.

Summary of 3 approaches to setup preconditions

1. Load from SQL DB backup
2. Use API requests
3. Use raw SQL statements

Comment: What Web framework are you using?

Comment: Selenium for web testing.

Comment: I mean on the backend.